# Git fatal error, repo not found after trying to push

Tags: git, github

So I was added to a private repo the other day. Cloned the repo, added 2 files, commited, went to push origin master typed in my username and pswd for my github and I get this:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/.../repo.git/' not found
```

removed the repo name and such but my question is why is there a slash at the end? Cloned the repo using the repo url on the github page. New to github so not sure if I did something wrong or something else is going on

Answer (score 0):

The trailing slash should not matter, but just in case, you can type:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/.../repo.git
```

For your push issue, check if you have [2FA activated](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa), in which case the password should be a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

The alternative is to test the SSH URL `git@github.com:<org>/<repo>`